# Http call inside Angular interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

I have this interceptor with a http call inside:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const apiConfigService = this.injector.get(ApiConfigService);
    const pingService = this.injector.get(PingService);

    let changedReq;
    let changedUrl;

    return pingService.ping().pipe(switchMap((data) => {
        apiConfigService.changeNetwork(data.type);
        changedUrl = apiConfigService.changeUrl(req.url);
        changedReq = req.clone({ url: changedUrl });

        return next.handle(changedReq);
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
        changedUrl = apiConfigService.changeUrl(req.url);
        changedReq = req.clone({ url: changedUrl });

        return next.handle(changedReq);
    }));
}
```

The `catchError` is raised on every http call fail not only on `pingService.ping()` error. How can I avoid this behaviour? I only want to trigger the `catchError` block when `ping()` fails.

Comment: You might just switch the order of operators (place `catchError` first and then `switchMap`) but I probably don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @martin I want to make the ping() http call on every http request in my app (using the interceptor), and I want to execute the catchError when the ping() call fails.

Comment: Isn't this what you're doing already?

Comment: @martin No, because the catchError block is called in every http request that fails not only in the ping() call.

Comment: That's why I suggested switching the order of operators

Comment: @martin Your solution works, but I dont understant why.

Comment: Because at the end of `switchMap` you return `return next.handle(changedReq);` which will handle the next request and after that you added `catchError` that captures errors from the request as well. If you switch the order then `catchError` can only capture errors from `ping()` and if any other request throws error it's after you used  `catchError` so it won't be caught.